# Can a string with a noteproperty be modified

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to modify a string without loosing any note properties it has?

```
$t = 'something'|Add-Member noteproperty one 1 -PassThru
$t.one
1
$t = 'else'
$t.one
<nothing here>
$t.value = 'else'  # The property 'value' cannot be found on this object
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: **No, you cannot modify the value of a `[string]` variable without *losing* any instance-level `NoteProperty` members** attached to the previous value.

---

The `NoteProperty` instance is associated with the specific object (string) instance you're piping to `Add-Member`.<sup>[1]</sup>

By assigning a *different* string instance to variable `$t` (`$t = 'else'`), the original instance is lost, and along with it the `NoteProperty` you've added.

Also note that a `[string]` instance, even if decorated with NoteProperty members, never has a `.value` property. However, cmdlets such as `ConvertTo-Json` may give the *appearance* that there's a `.value` property, because that's how they serialize a string or .NET primitive type with NoteProperty members.

---

Generally, it's **best to avoid adding NoteProperty members to *strings* and instances of .NET [*value types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)**, for two reasons:

- You cannot modify such instances *themselves*, you can only replace them with *modified copies* (stored in the same variable), and these copies invariably do *not* have the original's NoteProperty members.
- Even without modification, **passing NoteProperty-decorated strings or value types as *parameter values* results in loss of instance-level NoteProperty members under the following conditions**:

  - If the target parameter is **declared as a specific input type** and the input type is **either a *string* (`[string]`) or a .NET *primitive type***, which comprises the following value types: `[Bool], [Byte], [SByte], [Int16], [UInt16], [Int32], [UInt32], [Int64], [UInt64], [IntPtr], [UIntPtr], [Char], [Double], [Single]`.
  - Additionally - and this applies to *all* value-type instances as well as `[string]` - if the target parameter is **declared as an *array* of the specific input type** (e.g., if a `[datetime[]]`-typed parameter receives a decorated `[datetime]` instance)
  - However, passing such instances to *untyped* or - as is effectively the same - `[object]`- or `[object[]]`-typed parameters *does* preserve the decorations.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, for `[string]` instances only, it is an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper that the instance-level `NoteProperty` is associated with - if the `[string]` instance itself were used, problems could arise due to the .NET CLRs string-interning, where seemingly separate strings with the same content can point to the very same instance as an optimization - and an instance-specific `NoteProperty` shouldn't unexpectedly surface on what the user expects to be a different string.</sup>

Comment: Yes, and it is also lost when using `[string].Replace`.

Comment: In fact they are lost if you pass the string to a function that decorates the parameter with [string] or [string[]] too.  Pretty much everything seems to discard them.  I just hoped there was some trick I'd not heard of.

Comment: Good point, @DávidLaczkó; more generally, given that strings are _immutable_, any decoration is lost whenever a _modified copy_ is created - please see my update.

Comment: Exactly, as setting the variable to the modified copy is an assignment. Nice piece of work! My opinion is that this NoteProperty is not a good idea at all, too many things to consider. I would use a custom object instead.