# How to correctly validate parameter in powershell?

Tags: powershell, properties, add-member

team!

I have variable with type PSObject[] in my advanced function.

```
[Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "PsObject data." )]
[PSobject[]] $data,
...
```

but sometimes my input $data with type [string[]] is transforming to [PSObject[]] and i catch error while im using object property.

im trying to validate it by script

```
[Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "PsObject data." )]
[ValidateScript({ ( ( $_ -is [PSobject] ) -or ( $_ -is [PSobject[]] )  -or ( $_ -is [System.Object[]] ) ) })]
 $data,
```

but it has no effect, i see the $data with type [string[]], i`am continue to cath errors.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Every object in PowerShell is (transparently) wrapped in a `PSObject`, so converting to `PSObject` has no real effect. What is it you're hoping to enforce? If the input object needs to have specific properties you might want to define a custom `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: based on the comments, it sounds like your real question is:

> How can I validate that I'm able to attach new properties to the input objects with `Add-Member`?

For that, you need to *exclude* two kinds of input values:

- Objects of a *value type* (numerical types, `[datetime]`'s, anything passed by value in .NET really)
- Strings

(As [mklement0's excellent answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500028/712649), properties can be added to local copies of these types - but PowerShell cannot predictably "resurrect" them when passing values between adjecent commands in a pipeline, among other quirks)

You can validate that input objects do not fall in one of these buckets, like this:

```
[ValidateScript({$null -ne $_ -and $_.GetType().IsValueType -and $_ -isnot [string]})]
[psobject[]]$InputObject
```

---

`PSObject` is a generic wrapper type that PowerShell uses internally to keep track of extended properties and members attached to existing objects.

For this reason, *any object* can be converted to `PSObject` implicitly - in fact, PowerShell does so every time an object passes from one command to another across `|` in a pipeline statement - and it has no real effect in terms of enforcing specific input object traits.

If you want to ensure that an object has specific properties, the best option is to define a specific datatype with the `class` keyword:

```
class MyParameterType 
{
  [string]$Name
  [int]$Value
}

function Test-MyParameterType
{
  param(
    [MyParameterType[]]$InputObject
  )

  $InputObject |ForEach-Object {
    $_.GetType() # this will output `[MyParameterType]`
    $_.Name # now you can be sure this property exists
  }
}
```

You can now pass instances of the declared type to the function parameter:

```
$mpt = [MyParameterType]::new()
$mpt.Name = 'Name goes here'

Test-MyParameterType -InputObject $mpt
```

But PowerShell can also implicitly convert custom objects to the desired target type if they have matching properties:

```
$arg = [pscustomobject]@{
  Name = 'A name'
  Value = Get-Random
}

# This will return [PSCustomObject]
$arg.GetType() 

# But once we reach `$_.GetType()` inside the function, it will have been converted to a proper [MyParameterType]
Test-MyParameterType -InputObject $arg
```

---

If you want to validate the existence of specific properties and potentially their value *without explicit typing*, you have to access the hidden `psobject` memberset of the object in the validation script - note that it'll validate one item at a time:

```
function Test-RequiredProperty
{
  param(
    [ValidateScript({ $_ -is [PSObject] -and ($prop = $_.psobject.Properties['RequiredProperty']) -and $null -ne $prop.Value })]
    [PSObject[]]$InputObject
  )
}
```

Now, if we pass an object with a `RequiredProperty` property that has some value, the validation succeeds:

```
$arg = [pscustomobject]@{
  RequiredProperty = "Some value"
}

# This will succeed
Test-RequiredProperty -InputObject $arg

# This will fail because the property value is $null
$arg.RequiredProperty = $null
Test-RequiredProperty -InputObject $arg

# This will fail because the property doesn't exist
$arg = [pscustomobject]@{ ADifferentPropertyName = "Some value" }
Test-RequiredProperty -InputObject $arg
```

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I must have misunderstood your question. You said "i catch error while im using object property." - but you don't want to test whether the input object has that specific property afterall?

Comment: Thank you, for complete answer!
Im my case i`am just want to know base type. Not to test properties types.

Comment: Currently i`am do it by validate type in my code

```powershell
if ( ( $Data -is [PSobject] ) -or ( $Data -is [PSobject[]] ) -or ( $Data -is [System.Object[]] )  ){
    $ValidDataType = $true
}
Else {
    Add-ToLog -Message "Data should be of type [PSObject[]]! But type is [$( $data.gettype() )]. " -Display -Status "error"
    $ValidDataType = $false
}
```

Comment: I want to make the same by using ValidateScript.

Comment: But _why_? What's the point of validating the type if not to ensure that it has the correct members/properties that you expect to use? :)

Comment: This function display data in color table format. I dont know all property types. It normal if they converted to string.

Comment: Can you add the part of the function that fails (because `[string[]]` is accepted as `[psobject[]]`) [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69494996/edit)? Strings have a `Length` property, so if you aren't accessing specific properties I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve

Comment: for example: $DataCopy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Num' -Value 0

Comment: $SerialData = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Data)
            $DataCopy   = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($SerialData)

Comment: All you need for that is: `[ValidateScript({-not $_.GetType().IsValueType -and $_ -isnot [string]})]`

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):

While **it is *not advisable* to decorate instances of *[.NET value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)* and *strings* with ETS ([Extended Type System](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763)) properties** via  [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member), **you *can* do it**, using the following idiom.

```sh
# Works with any non-$null object.
# Note the use of -PassThru
# Add -Force to override an existing property.
$decoratedObject = $object | Add-Member -PassThru foo bar
```

<sup>Note: The `Add-Member` call is short for: `Add-Member -PassThru -NotePropertyName foo -NotePropertyValue bar`; that is, a property named `.foo` with value `'bar'` is added.</sup>

`-PassThru` is only strictly needed if `$object` is a *string* (type `[string]`).

To demonstrate:

```sh
$decoratedNumber = 42 | Add-Member -PassThru foo bar1 
$decoratedString = 'baz' | Add-Member -PassThru foo bar2
# Access the .foo property on each:
($decoratedNumber, $decoratedString).foo # -> 'bar1', 'bar2'
```

***Why* doing so isn't advisable:**

The decorating properties:

- are *discarded* when passing or casting decorated value-type instances to parameters of the same type or when modifying the variable's value:

  ```sh
  PS> ++$decoratedNumber; $decoratedNumber.foo + '!'
  !  # !! Property was discarded. 

  PS> & { param([int] $num) $num.foo + '!' } $decoratedNumber
  !  # !! Property was discarded. 

  # Only *untyped* parameters preserve the decorations:
  PS> & { param($num) $num.foo + '!' } $decoratedNumber
  bar1!
  ```
- can unexpectedly surface in *serialization* contexts; e.g.:

  ```sh
  PS> $decoratedNumber | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
  {"value":42,"foo":"bar1"}

  # Casting to the original type helps:
  PS> [int] $decoratedNumber | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
  42
  ```

Additionally, for `[int]` instances specifically, values between `0` and `100` are internally *cached* by PowerShell (for performance reasons), so the decorations may unexpectedly surface in later, unrelated variables:

```sh
 PS> $decorated = 42 | Add-Member -PassThru foo bar1; $other = 42; $other.foo
 bar1 # !! Unrelated use of 42 is decorated too.
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59313217/45375).